# Type Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: bool treeFromString(const ? &, KDL::Tree &) '

Tags: c++, eclipse, invalid-argument

Using Eclipse
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800

Can someone please explain why I have `"const ? &"` in uild error

```
Type Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: bool treeFromString(const ? &, KDL::Tree &) '
```

"treeFromString" Definition is

```
bool treeFromString(const std::string& xml, KDL::Tree& tree);
```

Full Code given below

```
#include "kdl_parser/kdl_parser.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Check to see if xml file provide
    if (argc != 2){
    std::cerr  << "Usage: full_info input.xml" << std::endl;
    return -1;
    }

    //Get the entire file
    std::string xml_string;
    std::fstream xml_file(argv[1], std::fstream::in);

    while ( xml_file.good() )
    {
        std::string line;
        getline( xml_file, line);
        xml_string += (line + "\n");
    }
    xml_file.close();

    //Obtain KDL tree, exit if invalid
    KDL::Tree kdl_tree;

    if (!kdl_parser::treeFromString(xml_string, kdl_tree)){
        std::cerr << ("Failed to construct kdl tree") << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is  treeFromString()? how is it defined?

Comment: definition as above and here     bool treeFromString(const std::string& xml, KDL::Tree& tree);

Comment: And somewhere before that we'll eventually find `#include <string>`, right ? *Code* would sure be nice.

Comment: Sounds like an incorrect forward declaration of `std::string` somewhere in `kdl_parser.hpp`.  Note that `std::string` is NOT a class, it's a typedef for a concrete instance of the `std::basic_string` template.

Comment: I think it has something to do with eclipse as when I make from terminal all compiles without errors and run accordingly. It is quite frustrating as the debugger exits past this point, what would make eclipse think that there is a "invalid argument error" and not recognize string argument.